# Understanding the syntax

Tags: matlab, sift

I have this couple of lines which is difficult to understand..

```
oframes1 = do_localmax(  difofg.octave{o}, 0.8*thresh, difofg.smin  ) ; 
oframes = [oframes1 , do_localmax( - difofg.octave{o}, 0.8*thresh, difofg.smin)] ;
```

here,

1. do_localmax is a function
2. thresh is a variable
3. difofg is also a function

I understand that the 1st line calls the function and passes the parameters but it is difficult understanding the second line and also what kind of syntax is difofg.octave{o}

Comment: You say `difofg` is a function. Can you show how it is defined? `which difofg` should tell you the path to the function if it exists - but I agree with Dougal it's more likely a struct, based on how it appears to be used. What is the value of `o`?

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically:

`difofg` is not a function; it's a variable, probably a [struct](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html) or a [class object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/begin-using-object-oriented-programming.html). `difofg.octave` and `difofg.smin` get the element named `octave` or `smin` from that struct/object.

`difofg.octave` is apparently a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html), and `difofg.octave{o}` gets the `o`th element of that cell array.

The second line creates an array with two elements: the first is `oframes1`, and the second is the result of the second call to `do_localmax`. Maybe this equivalent code will make it clearer what's happening:

```
oframes1 = do_localmax(  difofg.octave{o}, 0.8*thresh, difofg.smin); 
oframes2 = do_localmax( -difofg.octave{o}, 0.8*thresh, difofg.smin);
oframes = [oframes1, oframes2];
```